# Can't create new WebApplication

Tags: web-application

When I try to create a web application, an *error message* with **"Add Connectionsstrings is an invalid token"** always pops up.

Investigating in the *log file* returns that it is **"unable to activate WebApplication-scoped feature 'docmarketplacesafecontrols'(id) for this web application"**.

Where can I find this feature and what do I have to do to enable it and subsequently create a web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try activate the feature with powershell.

```
Enable-SPFeature –identity ["MyCustom" or ID] -URL http://[Site  ]
```

Reference: [SharePoint 2013: List of Features "ID, DisplayName, CompatibilityLevel and Scopes](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18729.sharepoint-2013-list-of-features-id-displayname-compatibilitylevel-and-scopes.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1)